# Not able to Add file using PendAdd

Tags: tfs-2015

I am using VS 2015. I am using TFS 2015 dlls. For adding new file, I am using workspace.PendAdd(filename).

But its not adding file to TFS. And same thing works with 2013 dlls.  Please suggest solution if anyone knows about this. I tried using Workstation.Current.EnsureUpdateWorkspaceInfoCache() but it did not work.

Regards,

Chaitrali

Answer (score 3):

I found alternative to above issue resolution.

I run Process with C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe - command line parameter to add file.

For ex.

```
Process myProcess = new Process(); 
ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("TFS EXE Path", "add " + '"' + FileName + '"'); 
myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
myProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = TFSLocalPath; 
myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo; 
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 
myProcess.Start();
```

Regards,

Chaitrali